# Handling connection errors in node.js ssh-exec?

Tags: node.js, ssh

I am using npm ssh-exec and it's great, just don't know how to handle connection errors or auth failures

```
exec('ls -lh', {
  user: 'ubuntu',
  host: 'my-remote.com',
  key: myKeyFileOrBuffer,
  password: 'my-user-password'
}).pipe(process.stdout)
```

If I get  error i.e. ssh2 'USERAUTH_FAILURE ' how do I handle it, where to put err callback ?